# Can I Convert multiple excel books in one pdf? (no using itextsharp)

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I want to convert multiple excel books (not sheets) to 1 PDF file. I don't want to use itextsharp because I need to purchase for commercial. 
Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a little complex, what I think is that maybe you can convert the excel docs to PDF first and then merge them to a single PDF doc. what is your thought? How is your plan going?

You can refer the following article, the main thought is to convert office files to pdf then merge them.

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/46252-Convert-and-Merge-Office-Files-to-One-PDF-File-in-C.aspx

To get better help, perhaps show more information like diNN's comment above is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used:

```
public static class ExcelMergeExtension
{
    public static ExcelFile Merge(this ExcelFile destination, string sourcePath)
    {
        var sourceFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sourcePath);
        var source = ExcelFile.Load(sourcePath);

        foreach (var sourceSheet in source.Worksheets)
            destination.Worksheets.AddCopy(
                string.Format("{0}-{1}", sourceFileName, sourceSheet.Name),
                sourceSheet);

        return destination;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new PdfSaveOptions() { SelectionType = SelectionType.EntireFile };

        ExcelFile.Load("Book1.xlsx")
                 .Merge("Book2.xlsx")
                 .Merge("Book3.xlsx")
                 .Save("Books.pdf", options);
    }
}
```

The code uses [GemBox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview) library which has free and commercial version, however note that free one does have some size limitations.
Anyway it worked great for me and I hope it helps you too.